# Can I use css wildcard selectors with an ampersand in Less?

Tags: css, less

I'm using [less](http://lesscss.org/) for CSS, and have this code. The significant part is that I want to lower the down chevron glyphicon 4 pixels:

```css
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    &.glyphicon-chevron-down {
        top: 4px;
    }
}
```

I'd also like to lower **up** glyphicons, and I'd like to use a css wildcard selector. Something like this (this code doesn't work):

```css
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    &[class^="glyphicon-chevron-"] {
        top: 4px;
    }
}
```

**Can I do this?**

Comment: Can you do this? Why just to not [try](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.glyphicon%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2020px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20padding%3A%200%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26.glyphicon-chevron-down%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20top%3A%204px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%5Bclass%5E%3D%5C%22glyphicon-chevron-%5C%22%5D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20top%3A%204px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)? (your only mistake is unmatched extra `}`).

Comment: Although the double class seems to be redudand (can it really ever be `.not-glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-down`? So I believe not nested `.glyphicon-chevron-*` should be enough).

Comment: I did try it (and thanks for catching the syntax error – that was in my simplified SO question, but not my code)

Comment: See the answer below. Also note that the `top` property need either `absolute` or `relative` position (it won't have any effect by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because, I'm assuming, the actual class string doesn't really start with `glyphicon-chevron-`, but instead starts with `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-`.

I would try

```
.glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: green;
  &[class^="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-"] {
    color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, use the wildcard where `[attr*=value]` "represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
.glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: green;
  &[class*="glyphicon-chevron-"] {
    color: red !important;
  }
}
```

edit: This also doesn't need to be nested at all, the attribute selector would just work. But I understand you might want to be more specific for some reason or keep your code together for some reason. If you just changed the order of the class string around, your original code would work too (other than the mismatched curly brace)